# How to call .py on all xml files?

Tags: python, xml, operating-system, subprocess, sys

I'm calling a `.py` inside a python script to read `.xml` files. My code looks like this :

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess


subprocess.call(["python", "/home/sky/DBT/test.py", "--host=PC", "--file=/home/sky/data/myfile.xml"])
```

for a single `.xml` file it works perfectly. But when i want to run my `.py` on all my `.xml`files it does not work. I tried this loop :

```
for f in ("/home/sky/data/*.xml"):
  subprocess.call(["python", "/home/sky/DBT/test.py", "--host=PC", "--file=f"])
```

but it does not work for all `.xml` files in my directory. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

path = "/home/sky/data/"
for filename in os.listdir(path):   #Iterate Your DIR
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):    #Check if file is XML
        subprocess.call(["python", "/home/sky/DBT/test.py", "--host=PC", "--file=/home/sky/data/{0}".format(filename)])   #Execute Command
```

Comment: could you please tell me how can I add a condition to this code to read just new files of my `/data/` directory (by hour for eg 24 hours ago) or from last execution time? @Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

1. In your for loop, you are iterating over the string "/home/sky/data/*.xml". Thus, variable f points to a single character inside the string.
2. In "--file=f", "f" is just a character inside the string "--file=f".

Addressing your problem, you should be doing something like

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
```

where 'directory' is your folder and filename is the file you need. Note you should check filename to be an xml file.